# CORAID using only 1 of the 2 available NICs for AoE traffic

Tags: performance, storage-area-network

We got 6 CORAID shelves in my workplace. On 2 of them I see AoE traffic on only 1 of the 2 NICs that are attached to the SAN switch. We got jumbo frames enabled on all devices.

Both NICs show up when I issue the **aoe-interfaces** command.

This wouldn't bother me too much if the throughput performance observed on the "bad" shelves using bonnie++ wasn't half of the result of the "good" shelves.

The "good" shelves are older SR1521 model and they have ReiserFS on their LUNS - not that I think it makes a difference - and the "bad" shelves are newer SR2421 model and have JFS.

Any help as to what is going on and how to rectify this would be greatly appreciated.

BTW: even the lower performing shelves outperform another iSCSI device we got, but that is another story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it is possible this is caused by an old AoE driver. The problem servers are using v32 of the AoE drivers and the good servers are using v47.

I will upgrade the drivers and post the observed results here.

*** update

the new drivers did the trick and now i have AoE traffic on both NICs on all servers!

Comment: wow, crazy, but that's great that you figured it out.

Comment: I am not sure that's what is causing the issue yet, but I hope it is!

I can't touch the servers until tomorrow, but I will post results back...